# Arduino is not uploading on the board

Tags: embedded

I am using windows 8.1 and I'm getting the following error, when I try to upload:

```
rdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x75

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x75

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x75

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x75

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x75

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x75

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x75

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x75

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x75

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x75

Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
```

This report would have more information with "Show verbose output during compilation" option enabled in File -> Preferences.

The following error pops. Before this the code used to upload but no longer.
thank you

Comment: That does not look like a programming problem according to site-rules.

Comment: @Olaf development tool questions are explicitly on topic, so the close reason currently showing is improper.  However, the question is presently too short on details to be answerable with anything more than general suggestions, and so off topic for that reason.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: This looks like an OS/Hardware problem, much like "my mouse does not work, but I get kernel error messages". Not every question - no matter how presented - which involves SW-development tools is on-topic.

Comment: No, it is most commonly a not doing it right problem.

Answer (score 1):

This happens

- If the board selected is incorrect
- if the selected COM port is not correct
- if anything is plugged into pin 0 or 1
- if your atmega chip soesnot contain bootloader
- if the microcontroller (atmega 328 or 168) has blown out